# Re-render component with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush strategy on value change

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive, angular-reactive-forms

I have `mat-option` which updates its value dynamically and I need it to be updated on value change. Unfortunately it has OnPush ChangeDetectionStrategy and it doesn't detect it automatically.

Currently I made a workaround with *ngFor:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let value of [dynamicValue]" [value]="value">{{value}}</mat-option>
```

this code creates a one element table with value and this way it detects the change of "dynamicValue" and re-creates a `mat-option` component every time it changes. Is there any better way to do it?

I know I can do `parentSelect.options.notifyOnChanges()` but it's complicated to do in my code cause in reality `dynamicValue` is a form control and it uses nested templates and I would need to keep reference to all elements, manually manage subscriptions to `formControl.valueChanges` and call `notifyOnChanges` in loop so I would like to do it purely in view.

Comment: try Observable for setting value, every time value changes observable emit and it will have a new value this should solve your problem https://angular.io/guide/observables

Comment: value is an observable already - it's FormControl. But how to bind observable as a value in view?

Comment: If its Observable then you should use async pipe to subscribe in template view i.e `[value]="value | async"`